# Regex to find several appearances of a regex

Tags: regex

I'm failing to find the correct regex to solve this adaptation.
From

```
<td> foo </td>
<td> bar </td>
|
<td> two foo </td>
<td> two bar </td>
|
```

I want to get to

```
<tr>
  <td> foo </td>
  <td> bar </td>
</tr></tr>
  <td> two foo </td>
  <td> two bar </td>
</tr>
```

By means of identifying N repetitions of the regex `<td>(.*)</td>`.

Could I get some help?

Thanks!

#EDIT: I am generating the html code myself from a different format ( initial input was

```
| foo | bar | | twofoo | twobar |
```

and I'm generating it from such).

I am doing the conversion on JS, but for trying it out I'm using https://regex101.com/, if it is useful to know.

Comment: [You should not use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5784924). Try an HTML parser instead.

Comment: Also, if you are not using code to parse HTML, but want to use "find and replace" in a text editor/IDE, please add details of which tool you use and the regex flavour it uses if you know it

Comment: If you just want to match a pattern repeated N times, I believe you're looking for the {} notation.  Would this work: `(?:<td>.*?</td>\R){N}` where `N` is the number of repetitions (2 in your example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, starting from your original input, I'd treat each part (beginning of table / between `td`s / between `tr`s / end of the table) separately. It's easier and you process each part once.

You can add a space or `\s` in the regexes depending if you want to keep the space around your words, I didn't to match your expected output.

In this order:

begin: `^\|` -> replace with `<tr>\n  <td>`

end: `\|$` -> replace with `</td>\n</tr>`

between `tr`s: `\| \|` -> replace with `</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n  <td>`

finally, between `td`s: `\|` -> replace with `</td>\n  <td>`

Exemple with js:

```js
var input = '| foo | bar | | twofoo | twobar |';

input = input.replace(/^\|/, '<tr>\n  <td>');
input = input.replace(/\|$/, '</td>\n</tr>');
input = input.replace(/\| \|/g, '</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n  <td>');
input = input.replace(/\|/g, '</td>\n  <td>');

console.log(input);
```